# jquery selector when a child element satisfies a criteria

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn">
<i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>
</a>
```

I need to write a jQuery selector for:

Anytime an anchor is clicked that has a tag inside of it of class='icon-thumbs-up', then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use the [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method

```
$('a').has('.icon-thumbs-up').click(){ // <-- all anchor that has descendant with class .icon-thumbs-up
     // code here
});
```

If the elements are changed/added dynamically.. you can use delegation

```
$('body').on('click','a', function(){
     if($(this).has(".icon-thumbs-up")){
         //code here
     }
});
```

Replacing `body` with the closest parent that is available when dom is loaded

Comment: if ($(this).has(".icon-thumbs-up").length) {

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

It turns out there *is* a selector called [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) which can help you achieve your goal:

```
$('body').on("click", "a:has(.icon-thumbs-up)", function(){
      // do something
});
```

Comment: This is tough slogging trying to find the best 1 line of code.  Thanks though!